# how to show this manipulation in the integral

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let we have:

$$G(t)=y_1(t)\int y_2(s)ds$$

when we take the limits as:

$$G(t)=y_1(t)\int^t_{t_0} y_2(s)ds$$

then is it possible to write it as:

$$G(t)=y_1(t)\int^t_{t_0} y_2(s)ds=\int^t_{t_0} y_1(t)y_2(s)ds$$

if so how it is possible. could you please explain.

Comment: Sure, $y_1(t)$ depends only on $t$ and therefore is treated as a constant inside the integral with respect to $s$.

Comment: here, we take the limits as t and $t_0$. do the limits have anything in related to take $y_1(t)$ as constant?

Comment: The $t$s in the limit are numbers right? Or is $t$ in the upper limit actually a variable?

Comment: yes,the upper limit is variable

Comment: Well actually it doesn't matter. Inside the integral, $s$ is the variable, everything else is a constant.

Comment: @Nameless thank  you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with fixing $t = t_1$. Let $A = y_1(t_1)$. This is a constant now.

Then apply the linearity of the integral:

$$A
\int_{t_0}^{t_1}y_2(s) ds= \int_{t_0}^{t_1}Ay_2(s) ds
$$

In other words:
$$y_1(t)
\int_{t_0}^{t}y_2(s) ds= \int_{t_0}^{t}y_1(t) y_2(s) ds
$$
This is true for every $t$, as we did not use any particular property of $t_1$.